# Accessing authorization header in django APIView

Tags: django

I have a Django APIView that requires authentication before the data can be fetched. The user token making the request is sent from a react front-end. The program works using a function view, but the returned data is formatted in a way I don't like. Something like [{"model":"product.product", "key":2, "fields":[{"name": "product one"} ... and so on]}] even including the model's name. For that reason, I reverted to using an APIView. Unfortunately, with APIView, it doesn't work at all, giving the error "Given token not valid for any token type". I'm convinced the problem is with the way I'm accessing the authorization header in the case of the APIView because if I remove the authorization part, the code works. That suggests to me that there must be a different way of accessing header information in APIView.
May I ask:
(1) If anyone has an idea of the right way to access the request header when using APIView.
(2) The right response class to use in order to have a proper object like {id: 1, name:"product one", price: 100) etc returned in the case of a function view. By the way, I'm using the google firebase authentication mechanism.
Below are the two views:

```
class SingleProduct(APIView):
     def get(self, request, slug):
        authorization_header = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        token = authorization_header.replace("Bearer ", "")
        try:
           decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(token)
           product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug) 
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "No product found"})
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And the function view that works is:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
    def single_product(request, slug):
        authorization_header = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        token = authorization_header.replace("Bearer ", "")
        try:
            decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(token)
            product = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)
            result = {"data": serialize("json", product)}
        except: 
            return JsonResponse({"data":"No product found"})
        return JsonResponse(result)
```

The header part of the front end is:

```
const config = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
      };
```

In summary, my goal is to know the right way to access the token (authorization header) in the APIView or be able to format the response data as a proper object with the function view.

Answer (score 0):

in both variants you can use `jmespath` for:

1. getting `headers.Authorization` from `request` if it's a dict type. for repairing APIView.
2. getting the only things you need from `result` in function view

Comment: Your answer is not clear to me. Can you please demonstrate with codes

Comment: @Mart function view returns something like `[{"model":"product.product", "key":2, "fields":[{"name": "product one"} ... and so on]}]` whereas you need something like `{id: 1, name:"product one", price: 100}`. you can use jmethpath to get from function view return those things only that you need and so after that manipulation function view would return something like ` {id: 1, name:"product one", price: 100}`. read this: https://pypi.org/project/jmespath//

Comment: show the exact full example of the function view return then I can demonstrate code with jmethpath

Comment: Well, I finally got things working with the APIView. The issue I was having with it originally was that I had a simple_jwt authentication scheme set in the settings.py. That is the reason I was getting the authentication error I got with APIView. Now everything is working. So, no need for the function view anymore. Thanks